# Unable to add db_datawriter to user defined role

Tags: sql-server, security, role

I want to grant a user defined role, read and write permissions to the entire database and add users to it. I was unable to do this using GUI. So I tried the solution given at the link - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1141208-1526-1.aspx but it gives me the error mentioned below when I try to add db_datawriter to the role I created.

Cannot use the special principal 'db_datawriter'

The command I executed - `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DR_User', 'db_datawriter'`

Please help me figure out the right way to achieve this.

Comment: It seems you are doing the opposite to desired. You are trying to add role `[db_datawriter]` to `[DR_User]` principal.

Comment: Thanks for the response @i-one. That was suggested in the article I have mentioned in my question. Is there a way to grant read and write permissions to a user defined role other than adding the role as a member of fixed roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JKay, you are a little mistaken about the syntax of this command:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember [ @rolename = ] 'role',  
    [ @membername = ] 'security_account'
```

So in your particular case the command is:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datawriter', @membername = 'DR_User';
```

Comment: Hi @SmokingDBA, My understanding of the syntax is correct but my idea is wrong. I just realized that. Thanks :)